# HW Help: get char instead of get line C++

Tags: c++

I wrote the code below that successfully gets a random line from a file; however, I need to be able to modify one of the lines, so I need to be able to get the line character by character. 
How can I change my code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::istream::get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/) instead of [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/). Just read your string character by character until you reach `\n`, [EOF](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/eof/) or [other errors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/good/). I also recommend you read the full [`std::istream` reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/).

Good luck with your homework!

**UPDATE:**

OK, I don't think an example will hurt. Here is how I'd do it if I were you:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

static std::string
answer (const string & question)
{
    std::string answer;
    const string filename = "answerfile.txt";
    ifstream file (filename.c_str ());

    if (!file)
    {
        cerr << "Can't open '" << filename << "' file.\n";
        exit (1);
    } 

    for (int i = 0, r = rand () % 5; i <= r; ++i)
    {
        answer.clear ();
        char c;

        while (file.get (c).good () && c != '\n')
        {
            if (c == 'i') c = 'I'; // Replace character? :)
            answer.append (1, c);
        }
    }

    return answer;
}

int
main ()
{
    srand (time (NULL));

    string question;

    cout << "Please enter a question: " << flush;
    cin >> question;
    cout << answer (question) << endl;
}
```

... the only thing is that I have no idea why do you need to read string char by char in order to modify it. You can modify std::string object, which is even easier. Let's say you want to replace "I think" with "what if"? You might be better off reading more about 
[`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) and using `find`, `erase`, `replace` etc.

**UPDATE 2:**

What happens with your latest code is simply this - you open a file, then you get its content character by character until you reach newline (`\n`). So in either case you will end up reading the first line and then your do-while loop will terminate. If you look into my example, I did while loop that reads line until `\n` inside a for loop. So that is basically what you should do - repeat your do-while loop for as many times as many lines you want/can get from that file. For example, something like this will read you two lines:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i)
{
    do
    {  

        answerfile.get (answer);
        cout << answer << " (from line " << i << ")\n";
    }
    while (answer != '\n');
}
```

Comment: int r, number;
   srand(time(NULL));
   r=rand() % number +1;
   
   
  char answerchar;
  do{for (int i=0; i<r; i++)answerfile.get(answerchar);
   cout << answerchar;}while(answerchar !='\n');
  

Thank you! I tried it out, and now the rand isn't working. The program is just spitting out the first line of the file. :/

Comment: @VladLazarenko no, r and number both appear to be initialized as ints.

Comment: The rand was working in my original code, but once I changed it to char instead of line it quit working.

Comment: Oh, god... You are doing it wrong.. OK, give me a second, I will show you.

Comment: Oh gosh! I'm sorry, I think I actually was making the project more difficult for myself! My TA just told me to read the down the list of answers in order. So there is no need to generate a random answer to a question. I guess now I need to figure out how to do that... 
><;;; I'm really sorry for troubling everyone! I truly am a noob... T_T

Comment: @Jessica: Don't worry about it :) One day we all were n00bs in programming. Reading down the list is easy - you have already done that with your `getline` and `for` loop :-)

Comment: @Jessica: getline gets line out of a stream, if you have, say, two lines, and call getline twice, then you gonna get a second line... Anyways, just post your code so I can tell, otherwise I can only guess

Comment: @Jessica: OK, see my "UPDATE 2"

Comment: @Jessica: So read line by line, not character by character. Now I totally don't get what your problem is... Sorry.